# MongoDB: Embedded docs that do NOT match query

Tags: mongodb, filter

I am working on a Mongo database, where I need users to be able to specify dates when they won't be available. I started with this structure:

```javascript
{
    "_id": "demo-spe",
    "SC": [ { "SS": 14, "SA": [ 2, 3, 5 ] } ],
    "SU": [
        { "IY": 2013, "IM": 12, "ID": 30, "H0": 0, "N0": 0, "H1": 23, "N1": 59 },
        { "IY": 2013, "IM": 12, "ID": 31, "H0": 0, "N0": 0, "H1": 23, "N1": 59 }
    ]
}
```

Using this structure, if I want to know which users will be available on a certain date, that is, the `"SU"` array should NOT have a document that matches `IY:(year)`, `IM:(month)` and `ID:(day)`. I am really lost with `$and` and `$nin`, could please someone guide me?
Thanks, and sorry for the noob question and the non-descriptive fields! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `$elemMatch` and `$not` to do this.  `$elemMatch` to match against multiple fields in the same array element, and `$not` to perform a logical NOT on the expression:

```js
db.test.find({SU: {$not: {$elemMatch: {IY:2013, IM:12, ID:29}}}})
```